# Is Ubuntu visible on a Windows network?

Tags: windows, networking

In windows 7, after configuring the network as "home network", there is the option to create a 'home group' where all the computers on that network are visible. Can a windows machine see my Ubuntu system is connected to that network?

Answer (score 2):

To make a folder visible and create a share to see it in Windows, simply right-lick a folder (best from your home directory) and choose Sharing options in Ubuntu. Let your Ubuntu system install the required components and logout and login again. Now you can share files and folders with a windows system with your username and password you have set in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. I've tested this many times and it works just fine. You may run into some issues with Windows Vista and Windows 7 if you're trying to view the Windows system from Ubuntu, but viewing Ubuntu from Windows should be just fine.